# Extending nw.gui functionality in Node.js Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

So I'm building a node module for use with node-webkit that creates a new object and exports it. Standard fare. But [since Node has no access to the `nw-gui` module of node-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392756/node-module-nw-gui-not-found), I'm just passing it in as a parameter to the constructor. Something like this:

```
function Example(gui) {
    this.gui = gui; //Save for later
}

Example.prototype.createExampleMenu = function() {
    return new this.gui.Menu();
}

exports.example = Example;
```

Works great. But I'm trying to modify `.prototype` methods of node-webkit's inner modules, like `Menu` and `MenuItem`. Is the only way to modify those methods (or add new ones) in the constructor itself? If I try to add new prototype methods outside, it (obviously) fails since `this.gui` hasn't been set. Basically, I'm trying to make it nicer to add new prototype methods to node-webkit modules without doing it in the constructor. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way an expert but from what I understand of the implementation of node-webkit from reading its source code, I doubt you can modify any of the objects defined in `nw.gui`.

If you look at the implementation of Node's standard `require` function in a running node-webkit instance, you'll find:

```
function (name) {  
    if (name == 'nw.gui')    
        return nwDispatcher.requireNwGui();  
    return global.require(name);
}
```

which means that requires of `nw.gui` are very special indeed.

Rather than requiring JavaScript code, this returns an internal binary object that only appears to be a required library.

Looking a little deeper, we find the nwDispatcher.nwGui.Menu is defined as:

```
function Menu(option) {
  if (typeof option != 'object')
    option = { type: 'contextmenu' };

  if (option.type != 'contextmenu' && option.type != 'menubar')
    throw new String('Invalid menu type: ' + option.type);

  this.type = option.type;
  v8_util.setHiddenValue(this, 'items', []);
  nw.allocateObject(this, option);
}
```

which calls methods of the `nw` object, which is an object that is not available outside of this function, (i.e. the function acts as a closure over it.)

Further inspection of the various prototype methods of `nw.gui.Menu` shows that each call refers (internally) to this `nw` object to handle method dispatch to internally defined functions (written in C++).

So, rather than a group of standard JavaScript prototypical objects, the `nw.gui` module calls internal binary functions within the node-webkit runtime which are not exposed via its defined API.

#### UPDATE

From the [node-webkit wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/API-Overview-and-Notices):

**Do not change UI types' prototype.**

Comment: Yes, it says not to change the UI types' prototype. But I decided to add on functionality, it was worth it. See https://github.com/dylangattey/node-webkit-additions for how I did it, using the technique I outlined in my question. Not the prettiest of solutions, but it works.

Comment: Dylan, while you do indeed add useful functionality, the developers clearly state that modifying the prototype is a bad idea. I would contact them to find out why. At the very least, I would inform users of your module of the developers' warning so they can be better prepared should unexpected errors occur.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do so

Comment: Another thing you might consider, rather than extending njs-wk's intrinsic objects, would be to provide your new functionality via Adapter classes. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern