# How to create database within nodejs application code in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nedb

I'm trying to use [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) database for persistence of application data. I'm trying to use the following approach to connect to my database like the following:

```
var Datastore = require('nedb')
  , path = require('path')
  , db = new Datastore({ filename: path.join(require('nw.gui').App.dataPath, 'something.db') }
```

But unfortunatly it fails because this works only client code withit `<script></script>` tags in html file. How could I do same thing on server side?

Comment: node-webkit is something to work on desktop.  If you want server-side DB, you would use some AJAX calls to your server, I guess.  And the NEDB query logic would be on server, too.

Comment: @Timothy No I need to use database on local machine. Not server side

Comment: please clarify, what is your problem then? From index.html you could include something like db.js, and initialize db connection on window.onload.  Queries to DB can be done on other events, like clicking a link in HTML.  Would that work for you?

Comment: I need to initialize db on "server side" in `node-main` script

Comment: I see that you rewrote your question in another topic and already got your answer :)

Comment: No. I'm still unable to get work `require('nw.gui')` in nodejs context. But now I can see the following error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392756/node-module-nw-gui-not-found#answer-26321866

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the structure of your app? Maybe you can put it to github? In my own case it's all working, though I am not using nedb, but sqlite3 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you cannot require('nw.gui') in the nodejs context, because in the nodejs environment is no window. No window, no gui. So what you can do, is just create a `script` tag in your main file (index.html) with the src to your db.js file with the above content, it should work fine.

in index.html

```
<script src="db/db.js"></script>
```

in db/db.js

```
var Datastore = require('nedb')
,   path = require('path')
,   dbFile = path.join(require('nw.gui').App.dataPath, 'something.db')
,   db = new Datastore({ filename: dbFile })
```

Comment: Hey @Erik, I guess you already came across this problem ;) Anyway, this link should also help: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2280#issuecomment-54149072