# Cannot find module 'nw.gui' - node webkit updater

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to use node webkit updater for my aplication,but when i'm trying to test is(using npm test) or start it(using nmp start) i'm receiving this error [image] .Both commands are used from **Nodejs command prompt** .

The js file used is updaterClientABC.js and the error comes from this line: **var gui = require('nw.gui');**

This is my folder structure : [image]

Can you please tell me what should i do ? I admit that i am a beginner i've never worked with node-webkit.Some advices will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this thread:

[node module 'nw.gui' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392756/node-module-nw-gui-not-found)

So yes, this kind of thing is due to how NW.js gets called (directly or from within a project). I've run into this problem as well. In this case, in the above, you call `updaterClientABS.js` directly from node.js.  To run a node-webkit project you need to load it via the NW.js binary, which in turn requires node.js.

It's also possible, as was my problem with this, that I was trying to access the nw.gui within the Node context (vs browser context). My solution was to access it via the browser context (which has more global access, not just Node.js objects).